# C++ value_type::second_type compiler error inside template

Tags: c++, templates, decltype

I get compiler error when using decltype inside template function. Example is pretty self-explanatory. Help?

```cpp
template<class T>
void foo(T&& m)
{
    auto t = (decltype(m)::value_type::second_type::value_type*)3; // compiler error
}

int main()
{
    unordered_map<int, map<float, double>> m;
    foo(m);
    auto t = (decltype(m)::value_type::second_type::value_type*)3; // ok, t is a std::pair<const float, double>*
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `m` in the function, you need to remove the reference (and add `typename`):

Example:

```
typename std::remove_reference_t<decltype(m)>::value_type::second_type::value_type* t;
```

Or simply use `T`:

```
typename T::value_type::second_type::value_type* t;
```

Comment: Thank you! The first solution worked, but the second didn't for some reason

Comment: @user14789259 Great. You're welcome! Odd that the second didn't work though. Note that the type is `std::pair<const float, double>*`, not `std::pair<const float*, double>*` that you wrote as a comment.

Comment: True! I will fix that

Comment: I also suggest not casting `3` to `decltype(m)::value_type::second_type::value_type*`. That looks risky.

Comment: Yeah, that was just a random number for the example :)

Comment: @user14789259 I see. `nullptr` would be a better random value for the example :-)